# JSON converter converting double value to scientific notations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my Web Api controller I am sending my model, to Angular.js frontend, in which I got one field type of nullable double. The value of that field is 0.0000001.

Now when I am inspecting that value on controller level it is showing it as 0.0000001(exactly what I want) but on front end which is javascript(Angular.js) it is getting converted to 1E-07 which is a scientific notation of that.

Now is there anyway Can I solve this on my controller level without using anything at frontend. I can easily fix this at frontend level but couldn't find anything at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to solve it in the controller if it's the frontend which formats it in a different way?

From the computer point of view the number is the same, and the change is only on the visualization format.

If your frontend changes the format for some reason do change it.

The only solution, if you don't need to treat it as a number on the front end, is to convert it to formatted string, and send the value to the front end as string. However, if it is treated as number in the client side, you'll lost the format. Remember that JavaScript is dynamically typed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can fix this in controller level without using anything at front end.
Parse your result before sending it to front end. like  this

`using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
..

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
objectString = serializer.Serialize(new MyObject());`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with @JotaBe: this clearly isn't controller responsibility.

Anyway, if you want to this you can: in ASP.Net Web API the JSON serialisation is performed by [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm). The library offers various way to control it's processes, one of these is writing a customer converters and configure it via attributes, [see here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).